# How to improve cassandra 3.0 read performance and throughput using async queries?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    user_id text,
    ad_id text,
    date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, ad_id)
);
```

The lengths of the user_id and ad_id that I use are not longer than 15 characters.

I query the table like this:

```
Set<String> users = ... filled somewhere 
Session session = ... builded somewhere
BoundStatement boundQuery = ... builded somewhere
(using query: "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_id=?")

List<Row> rowAds = 
      users.stream()
          .map(user -> session.executeAsync(boundQuery.bind(user)))
          .map(ResultSetFuture::getUninterruptibly)
          .map(ResultSet::all)
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .collect(toList());
```

The Set of users has aproximately 3000 elements , and each users has aproximately 300 ads.

This code is excecuted in 50 threads in the same machine, (with differents users), (using the same Session object)

The algorithm takes between 2 and 3 seconds to complete

The Cassandra cluster has 3 nodes, with a replication factor of 2. Each node has 6 cores and 12 GB of ram.

The Cassandra nodes are in 60% of their CPU capacity, 33% of ram, 66% of ram (including page cache)
The querying machine is 50% of it's cpu capacity, 50% of ram

**How do I improve the read time to less than 1 second?**

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After some answers(thank you very much), I realized that I wasn' t doing the queries in parallel, so I changed the code to:

```
List<Row> rowAds = 
     users.stream()
       .map(user ->  session.executeAsync(boundQuery.bind(user)))
       .collect(toList())
       .stream()
       .map(ResultSetFuture::getUninterruptibly)
       .map(ResultSet::all)
       .flatMap(List::stream)
       .collect(toList());
```

So now the queries are being done in parrallel, this gave me times of aprox 300 milliseconds, so great improvement there!.
**But my question continues, can it be faster?**
Again, thanks!

Comment: parellel stream help at all? for the get/all mapping more than the executeAsync

Answer (score 1):

```
users.stream()
          .map(user -> session.executeAsync(boundQuery.bind(user)))
          .map(ResultSetFuture::getUninterruptibly)
          .map(ResultSet::all)
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .collect(toList());
```

A remark. On the 2nd `map()` you're calling `ResultSetFuture::getUninterruptibly`. It's a blocking call so you don't benefit much from asynchronous exec ...

Instead, try to transform a list of Futures returned by the driver (hint: `ResultSetFuture` is implementing the `ListenableFuture` interface of Guava) into a Future of List

See: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: Hi @doanduyhai, thanks for the answer!, despite the fact that I am not using your tip, the question about why if I make all the request and block for the response it spends a lot of time from my app to cassandra and back is still a mistery?, the response time wouldn 't be around milliseconds?

Comment: if its a 0.5ms network hop, sequentially doing one after another (round trip) for 3000 users would take 3 seconds.

Comment: Hi @ChrisLohfink you were right! , see mi update in the question